# How to get a count of data points per each identified cluster?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I did clustering and got 3 clusters. Now, I want to get a data frame that returns the number of data points per each cluster. For example:

```
[Cluster, count]
[0,50]
[1,30]
[2,10]
```

This is how far I got:

```
X=array([[5.71585827e+00, 3.32320000e+04],
       [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00],
       [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00],
       ...,
       [9.57746479e-02, 3.40000000e+01],
       [7.01388889e-01, 1.01000000e+02],
       [9.70350404e-02, 3.60000000e+01]])

#Scale
X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)

# Compute DBSCAN
db = DBSCAN(eps=0.25, min_samples=10).fit(X)
core_samples_mask = np.zeros_like(db.labels_, dtype=bool)
core_samples_mask[db.core_sample_indices_] = True
labels = db.labels_

# Number of clusters in labels, ignoring noise if present.
n_clusters_ = len(set(labels)) - (1 if -1 in labels else 0)
n_noise_ = list(labels).count(-1)



df = pd.DataFrame({'cluster':list(set(labels)),'customers':len(X) })
df.head()

cluster customers
0       90
1       90
2       90
```

Of course, the column 'customers' is totally wrong! How can I get the right counts for each cluster class?

Comment: Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just count how many of each label occur?  Something like

`pd.Series(labels).value_counts()`

if you are using pandas.

Comment: Great! Sorry this was so trivial.